# Swipe left/right for a webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I have a series of enumerated webpages, and at the moment I have a left and a right arrow icon on each page to navigate to the previous/next page in the series.

My question: What is the simplest (!) way to implement swipe left/right gesture to do the same? (No other gestures--no complex solutions please, I am a bloody newbie!)

Thank you very much in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply store the first point the user touched down:

```
 var start = null;
 window.addEventListener("touchstart",function(event){
   if(event.touches.length === 1){
      //just one finger touched
      start = event.touches.item(0).clientX;
    }else{
      //a second finger hit the screen, abort the touch
      start = null;
    }
  });
```

Then if the finger lefts the screen, check if the offset is higher then a value:

```
 window.addEventListener("touchend",function(event){
    var offset = 100;//at least 100px are a swipe
    if(start){
      //the only finger that hit the screen left it
      var end = event.changedTouches.item(0).clientX;

      if(end > start + offset){
       //a left -> right swipe
      }
      if(end < start - offset ){
       //a right -> left swipe
      }
    }
  });
```

You might add additional checks e.g. if the delta y ( clientY) stays under a certain amount, or if the touchmove just goes in one direction. However thats optional and depends if you need to differ it from another swipe action. You could also make the needed swipe dependend off the pages width, e.g.:

```
var offset = window.clientX * 0.9; // the swipe mist be 90% of the windows size
```

[Test it](http://jsbin.com/nasonuwiri/1/edit?output)

Comment: Don’t forget to take up/down movement into account; when scrolling or swiping up, the touch often also moves horizontally, which could now cause unintended interactions

Comment: @Jonas w: That sounds very promising for me. My right arrow icon triggers the js function next(): <A href="javascript:next()"><IMG style="HEIGHT: 15px; WIDTH: 15px" alt=next src="media/right.png"></A>. Could you tell me how to insert this action into your js?

Comment: @newbieforever put next(); into the *a left to right swipe*

Comment: @Jonas w: Doesn't work at the moment... What would be the simplest command to put it into just to see that the browser detects the swipe gesture correctly?

Comment: @newbieforever add a few console.log("touch") (similar to the output ive added in the snippet) , then go to the touch device emulator in chrome and check if its working.

Comment: @Jonas w: Hm... I am testing the webpage on my Surface tablet. Should your jsbin.nasonuwiri.1.html show an effect on swipe left/right gestures?

Comment: @newbieforever yes it shows *left* , *right* on the screen... ( tested on multiple androids)

Comment: @newbieforever have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300962/touch-api-e-g-touchstart-not-working-in-ms-edge, looks like a windows problem :/

Comment: @Jonas w: Thank you very much!!! My pages work now on smartphone correctly. (I have to work on the Windows problem, but this is not urgent...)